# What is this hexadecimal in the utf16 format?

Tags: python, encoding, endianness, utf-16

```
print(bytes('ba', 'utf-16'))
```

Result :

```
b'\xff\xfeb\x00a\x00'
```

I understand utf-16 means every character will take 16 bits means `00000000 00000000` in binary and i understand there are 16 bits here `x00a` means `x00 = 00000000` and `a = 01000001` so both gives `x00a` it is clear to my mind like this but here is the confusion:

```
\xff\xfeb
```

1 - What is this ?????????

2 - Why `fe` ??? it should be x00

i have read a lot of wikipedia articles but it is still not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have,

```py
b'\xff\xfeb\x00a\x00'
```

This is what you asked for, it has three characters.

```py
b'\xff\xfe' # 0xff 0xfe
b'b\x00'    # 0x62 0x00
b'a\x00'    # 0x61 0x00
```

The first is U+FEFF (byte order mark), the second is U+0062 (b), and the third is U+0061 (a). The byte order mark is there to distinguish between little-endian UTF-16 and big-endian UTF-16. It is normal to find a BOM at the beginning of a UTF-16 document.

It is just confusing to read because the `'b'` and `'a'` look like they're hexadecimal digits, but they're not.

If you don't want the BOM, you can use `utf-16le` or `utf-16be`.

```
>>> bytes('ba', 'utf-16le')
b'b\x00a\x00'
>>> bytes('ba', 'utf-16be')
b'\x00b\x00a'
```

The problem is that you can get some garbage if you decode as the wrong one. If you use UTF-16 with BOM, you're more likely to get the right result when decoding.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misinterpreting the printout.

You have 3 16-bit words:

- `FFFE`: This is the byte-order mark required in UTF-16 ([Byte order mark - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)).
- `00`, followed by the 8-bit encoding of 'b' (that is shown as the character 'b' instead of using an `\x` escape sequence): This is the 16-bit representation of 'b'.
- `00`, followed by the 8-bit encoding of 'a': This is the 16-bit representation of 'a'.

Comment: why 3 ??? there are only two a and b where are 3 ???????

Comment: It's simply as he says. There is an extra word inserted at the start: the byte-order mark required by UTF-16. It's part of the UTF-16 encoding, not the source string itself.

Comment: Yes, the 1st 16-bit word is included in the UTF-16 encoding rule. For the lengthy details see https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings (look for discussions around BOM).

Answer (score 0):

You already got your answer I just wanted to explain it in my own words for future readers.

In UTF-16 encoding, It seems that `'a'` should occupy 16 bits or 2 bytes. The `'a'` itself needs 8 bits. The question is should I put the remaining zeroes before the value of `'a'` or after it? There are two possible ways:

`First:  01100001|00000000`
`Second: 00000000|01100001`

If I don't tell you anything and just hand you these, this would happen:

```py
First = b"0110000100000000"
print(hex(int(First, 2)))   # 0x6100
print(chr(int(First, 2)))   # 愀

Second = b"0000000001100001"
print(hex(int(Second, 2)))  # 0x61
print(chr(int(Second, 2)))  # a
```

So you can't say anything just by looking at these bytes. Did I mean to send you `愀` or `a` ?

### First Solution:

I myself tell you about this verbally. About the *"Ordering"*! Here is where "big-endian" and "little-endian" come into play:

```py
bytes_ = b"a\x00" # >>>>>> Please decode it with "Little-Endian"!
print(bytes_.decode("utf-16-le"))  # a - Correct.
print(bytes_.decode("utf-16-be"))  # 愀
```

So If I tell you about the endianness, you can get to the correct character.

You see, without any extra character we were able to achieve this.

### Second Solution

I can *"embed"* the byte ordering into the bytes itself without explicitly telling you! It is called BOM(Byte Order Mark).

```py
ordering1 = b"\xfe\xff"
ordering2 = b"\xff\xfe"

print((ordering1 + b"\x00a").decode("utf-16"))  # a
print((ordering2 + b"a\x00").decode("utf-16"))  # a
```

Now just passing `"utf-16"` to `.decode()` is enough. It can figure the correct byte out correctly. There is no need to tell about `le` or `be` it's already there.