# The byte-order in UTF8

Tags: text, unicode, binary-data

I've read a question elsewhere about "Why there isn't a need for the **Byte Order Mark** in UTF-8", especially regarding systems with different Endianness.

To me the TLDR; is that UTF-8 enforces you to write the same numbers in the same order to memory, those numbers being each byte of the code, and it always reads the same (byte by byte).

---

**A more extended explanation**

Some character could have the code `11100010 10000010 10101100`, and will be represented the same in any computer, that's because the utf8 indicates how to encode a character.

Each of those bytes will be read (as the decoding process would indicate.) one by one, so again, there is no ambiguity.

When the first byte starts with `111` they have to search for 3 bytes, and then use it for a look up / retrieve the string. This is how multi-byte characters are read.

Is this a correct explanation ? If you disagree, why and what is the correct reason ?

Comment: Yes. You got it right. Byte order matters [when you have utf-16](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74279394/13944524).

Comment: Byte order matters to UTF-32, too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite what you're asking so this might not be the answer you're looking for.

Byte order only matters when you're dealing with integer primitives that are larger than a single byte.

For example, if you're storing the number 5 as a 16-bit value, it would be naturally stored as the following on big-endian (e.g. ARM) hardware:

```
00000000 00000101
```

Whereas on little-endian (e.g. x86) hardware it would be stored as the following:

```
00000101 00000000
```

Since UTF-8 consists entirely of a stream of bytes, byte order is never a consideration. Yes, there are code points which require multiple bytes to represent, but reading and writing of those code points still needs to be done one byte at a time. The order of those bytes is well-defined, and the endianness of the hardware does not matter.